# Can you tap artifacts to an improvise cost to help pay for kicker costs?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If you have an [Inspiring Statuary](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=423827) on the field can you pay UU and tap two artifacts to play a kicked [Into the Roil](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=433018)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you **improvise** to pay the **total costs** of a spell and kicker is an **additional cost**.

This is per Comprehensive Rules:

> 702.125a Improvise is a static ability that functions while the spell with improvise **is on the stack**. “Improvise” means “For each generic mana in this spell’s **total cost**, you may tap an untapped artifact you control rather than pay that mana.”

Total cost is defined in the Casting Spells rules:

> 601.2f The player determines the **total cost** of the spell. Usually this is just the mana cost. Some spells have **additional** or alternative costs. (...)

And kicker is an additional cost:

> 702.32a Kicker is a static ability that functions while the spell with kicker **is on the stack**. “Kicker [cost]” means “You may pay an **additional** [cost] as you cast this spell.”

Comment: But isn't cost supposed to be paid before the spell is put on the stack?

Comment: @Acccumulation: See rules 601.2a, 601.2f. First you put the spell on the stack, then you choose targets, then you determine the cost, and finally you pay the cost.